# How to add a node group to the world environment?

Tags: python

How to add a node group to the world environment, then specify the `texture_coordinate.object` in the node group to an empty object with the specified name?

If not, create a new empty object, and then specify it.

[image]

```
import bpy


class NODE_PT_MAINPANEL(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Custom Node Group"
    bl_idname = "NODE_PT_MAINPANEL"
    bl_space_type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'New Tab' 

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator('node.test_operator')

def create_test_group(context, operator, group_name):
    
    custom_node_name = "autoname"

    test_group = bpy.data.node_groups.new(group_name, 'ShaderNodeTree')
    
    
    group_in = test_group.nodes.new('NodeGroupInput')
    group_in.location = (-200,0)
    test_group.inputs.new('NodeSocketFloat','Factor Value') #0
    test_group.inputs.new('NodeSocketColor','Color Input') #1
    
    
    group_out = test_group.nodes.new('NodeGroupOutput')
    group_out.location = (400,0)
    test_group.outputs.new('NodeSocketColor','Output')
    
    #node Texture Coordinate
    texture_coordinate = test_group.nodes.new("ShaderNodeTexCoord")
    if custom_node_name in bpy.data.objects:   #If there is an object called autoname, point to it
        texture_coordinate.object = bpy.data.objects[custom_node_name]
    
    #If there is no object called autoname, create one and point to it
    else: bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='SINGLE_ARROW', align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
          bpy.context.selected_objects[0].name = [custom_node_name]
          texture_coordinate.object = bpy.data.objects[custom_node_name]
    
    mask_node = test_group.nodes.new(type= 'ShaderNodeMix')
    mask_node.location = (0,0)
        
    mix_node = test_group.nodes.new(type= 'ShaderNodeMix')
    mix_node.location = (200,0)
    mix_node.blend_type = 'OVERLAY'
        
    link = test_group.links.new
    
    link(mask_node.outputs[0], mix_node.inputs[1])
    
    link(group_in.outputs[0], mix_node.inputs[0])
    link(group_in.outputs[1], mix_node.inputs[2])
    
    link(mix_node.outputs[0], group_out.inputs[0])
    
    return test_group
    
               
class NODE_OT_TEST(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Add Custom Node Group"
    bl_idname = "node.test_operator"
    
#The following code can only be used in the material node, how to make it use in the world environment?
    def execute(self, context):
        custom_node_name = [custom_node_name]
        my_group = create_test_group(self, context, custom_node_name)
        node_tree = context.object.active_material.node_tree
        new_node = node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeGroup")
        new_node.node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups[my_group.name]
        new_node.use_custom_color = True
        new_node.color = (0.5, 0.4, 0.3)
             
        return {"FINISHED"}
                
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(NODE_PT_MAINPANEL)
    bpy.utils.register_class(NODE_OT_TEST)
    
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NODE_PT_MAINPANEL)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NODE_OT_TEST)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was very well but it needed some fixes that I have done.

````
import bpy


class NODE_PT_MAINPANEL(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Custom Node Group"
    bl_idname = "NODE_PT_MAINPANEL"
    bl_space_type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'New Tab' 

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator('node.test_operator')

def create_test_group(context, operator, group_name):
    
    custom_node_name = "autoname"

    test_group = bpy.data.node_groups.new(group_name, 'ShaderNodeTree')

    group_in = test_group.nodes.new('NodeGroupInput')
    group_in.location = (-200,0)
    test_group.inputs.new('NodeSocketFloat','Factor Value') #0
    test_group.inputs.new('NodeSocketColor','Color Input') #1
    
    
    group_out = test_group.nodes.new('NodeGroupOutput')
    group_out.location = (400,0)
    test_group.outputs.new('NodeSocketColor','Output')
    
    so = bpy.context.object
    #node Texture Coordinate
    texture_coordinate = test_group.nodes.new("ShaderNodeTexCoord")
    if custom_node_name in bpy.data.objects:   #If there is an object called autoname, point to it
        texture_coordinate.object = bpy.data.objects[custom_node_name]
    
    #If there is no object called autoname, create one and point to it
    else: 
        bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='SINGLE_ARROW', align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
        bpy.context.object.name = custom_node_name
        texture_coordinate.object = bpy.data.objects[custom_node_name]
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = so
    mask_node = test_group.nodes.new(type= 'ShaderNodeMixRGB')
    mask_node.location = (0,0)
        
    mix_node = test_group.nodes.new(type= 'ShaderNodeMixRGB')
    mix_node.location = (200,0)
    mix_node.blend_type = 'OVERLAY'
        
    link = test_group.links.new
    
    link(mask_node.outputs[0], mix_node.inputs[1])
    
    link(group_in.outputs[0], mix_node.inputs[0])
    link(group_in.outputs[1], mix_node.inputs[2])
    
    link(mix_node.outputs[0], group_out.inputs[0])
    
    return test_group
    
               
class NODE_OT_TEST(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Add Custom Node Group"
    bl_idname = "node.test_operator"
    
#The following code can only be used in the material node, how to make it use in the world environment?
    def execute(self, context):
        custom_node_name = 'autoname'
        my_group = create_test_group(self, context, custom_node_name)
        node_tree = context.scene.world.node_tree
        new_node = node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeGroup")
        new_node.node_tree = bpy.data.node_groups[my_group.name]
        new_node.use_custom_color = True
        new_node.color = (0.5, 0.4, 0.3)
        return {"FINISHED"}
                
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(NODE_PT_MAINPANEL)
    bpy.utils.register_class(NODE_OT_TEST)
    
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NODE_PT_MAINPANEL)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NODE_OT_TEST)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````

Answer (score 2):

You can access worlds from `bpy.data.worlds`. If you want to get current scene's world's nodes, you can use `bpy.context.scene.world.node_tree.nodes`. Creating and connecting some new nodes could be something like:

```
import bpy 

HSV_node = bpy.context.scene.world.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeHueSaturation')
HSV_node.location = (-50,-50)
HSV_node.width = 400
HSV_node.inputs[0].default_value = 0.1
HSV_node.inputs[1].default_value = 0.4
HSV_node.inputs[2].default_value = 0.241

color_node = bpy.context.scene.world.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeRGB')
color_node.location = (-250,-50)
color_node.outputs[0].default_value = (0,0.5,0.8,1)

bpy.context.scene.world.node_tree.links.new(color_node.outputs[0],HSV_node.inputs[0])
```

You can enable Python tooltips in the user preferences:
[image]

This way you can hover your mouse over nodes or add menu items and see useful info:
[image]

Also autocomplete (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) functionality in Python console is very useful:
[image]